# Autostart flutter app on BOOT_COMPLETED for flutter application based on Android 10

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio, broadcastreceiver

I have a problem in my flutter app. I want to start my app on startup for android.

I use the codes, It is working very good on Android 8 and Android 9 but It is not working on Android 10

my receiver class

Ho do I have do

```
package com.arge24.assistant24_mobile;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import android.app.Activity;

import com.arge24.assistant24_mobile.MainActivity;

public class BootCompleteReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG_BOOT_BROADCAST_RECEIVER = "BOOT_BROADCAST_RECEIVER";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String message = "Service will be start. Please wait ";
        Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Log.d(TAG_BOOT_BROADCAST_RECEIVER, action);
        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equalsIgnoreCase(intent.getAction())) {

 

            startServiceByAlarm(context);
        
        }
    }

    private void startServiceByAlarm(Context context) {
        // Get alarm manager.
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        // Create intent to invoke the background service.
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK );
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long intervalTime = 600 * 1000;

        String message = "app activied... ";

         Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // Log.d(TAG_BOOT_BROADCAST_RECEIVER, message);

        // Create repeat alarm.
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, startTime, intervalTime, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

I used this codes in BootCompleteReceiver  class but  my problem did not change

```
  Intent thisIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
  thisIntent.setAction("android.intent.action.MAIN");
  thisIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
  thisIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
  context.startActivity(thisIntent);
```

My manifest file like this

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" package="com.arge24.assistant24_mobile">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />

  <application android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication" android:label="Assistant 24" android:allowBackup="false" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:showWhenLocked="true" android:turnScreenOn="true">
   
      <meta-data android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme" android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />

      <meta-data android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable" android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name="BootCompleteReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
 
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Same here, it works on Android 5.1 but not 6

Comment: Were you able to find the solution @Musa @Teddichiiwa?

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast I tried using Pending Intent and it works (for now).

Comment: @Teddichiiwa Could you pls share a code snippet, if possible.

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast please try the code below (Kotlin) and place it inside "BroadcastReceiver#onReceive" method:

val intent = Intent(context!!, MainActivity::class.java)

intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0)